# How to access a usb driver to directly send commands? C#

Tags: c#, usb, thermal-printer

I´m currently developing software to communicate with the TM-T88V Epson printer. Everything works fine via serial ports, however, I also need to be able to send and receive commands via USB (and later ethernet). I've found that this is considerably more complex than serial ports, there is no native library for controlling USB ports.

Most questions and tutorials on this topic refer to printing via System.Drawing.Printing, or using external downloaded libraries to access the bus. Also, there are a lot of references to using some of the System.Management classes to search for events and properties of the USB ports, quite useful, but no message interchange.
Nonetheless, what I think would be the best is to use the printer driver if possible and use it for this task, I guess that's what the driver is for... I'm definitely not an expert and I've only used serial communication for whatever reason through my major.

Basically, I want to detect, select, send and receive messages from a USB port. If the printer driver is up for this task great, if not whatever resource is useful. Note that I already have all the messages and message structure.

Comment: There should not be any change required for USB except to change the Com number.  Once that is working you could upgrade to automatically find the com number.

Comment: @jdweng COM number is for serial communication, I have no problem with that. The one I'm trying to do now is purely USB has no serial properties. It shows up in the device manager under the universal serial bus controllers as EPSON USB Controller for TM/BA/EU Printers.

Comment: A USB is a serial port!!! : universal SERIAL bus controllers

Comment: Yeah, but they don't work the same way. At least not in code as far as I know. If there is a way to declare any USB connected, like a printer, to work with C# System.IO.Ports.SerialPort please tell me. That would be amazing and I really need to work this out.

Comment: The USB is just an enhanced serial port.  Has higher speed and is Plug and Play.  As long as you keep in same connector it is same port number.  The traditional 25 pin connector on PC had both a Parallel Printer mode and a Serial Mode.  The USB enhanced the Serial Mode only.

Comment: Okey, and how do I access that port? Please, if you know how to solve this, give me a full answer below.

Comment: Can you get a list of serial port names?  See following : https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/105314/connect-to-specific-USB-device-in-C

Answer (score -3):

Here is very simple code to get started :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Ports;


namespace ConsoleApplication108
{
    class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] names = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

        }
    }

}
```